# jquerymobile page transistions without ajax

Tags: jquery-mobile

is there way to do jquery mobile page transitions when ajax is disabled?

As part of template I have

```
<script>
  $(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){
    $.extend(  $.mobile , {
      ajaxEnabled: false
    });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ajaxEnabled` is a global setting, which means page transitions are disabled even when specifically applying them to links with the `data-transition` attribute, so the short answer would be "no", alas.

However, if you really want the transitions, consider enabling ajax once more, and then overriding it for whatever scenario is a deal-breaker for you (e.g. if it's form submission, use the `data-ajax="false"` attribute on your `form` element). For links, you can override the ajax navigation model by either giving them a `target` attribute or setting the `rel` attribute to `external`. Not ideal I know, but may help?

Comment: what's weird is that that it did it on the first click, but then it just flickered instead of doing transition.  any idea?

Comment: @Ben Do you have any clue how to do it programmatically?

Comment: @YusrilMaulidanRaji I don't understand what you're asking. Transitions are done programmatically by default.

Comment: @Ben I mean for now, I use `$(":mobile-pagecontainer").pagecontainer("change", "destination.html", { transition: "slide"});` to transit my page to another page. But in default, it uses ajax. So, is there any way to use that event to move the page without ajax?

Answer (score 2):

well this works..

```
      // JQUERY MOBILE PAGE INIT
     $(document).on("pageinit", function () {
            $("#test").click(function (e) {
                $.mobile.changePage("/Home/Test", { transition: "flip" });
            });
        });

        // JQUERY MOBILE INIT
        $(document).bind("mobileinit", function () {
            $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
            $.mobile.defaultPageTransition = 'none';
            $.mobile.defaultDialogTransition = 'none';
            $.mobile.useFastClick = true;

        });

<a id="test"/>
```